# Can launching an app trigger the launch of another app?

Tags: macos, applications, applescript

When I launch a specific application in Mavericks I'd also like to automatically launch and execute another one.

Is it possible/how?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to launch both applications from a new third application such as a AppleScript applet?  Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AllInOne when I launch spotify I also launch an app that will make use of spotify but I don't want to launch it at system startup

Answer (score 6):

Open Automator, and choose 'Application' from the pane that appears.

In the sidebar, there should be an item called 'Utilities'. Click this, and drag two 'Launch Application' actions into the main workflow pane. In the first one, choose the application you want to use with Spotify, and in the second one, choose Spotify. (See the picture below.)

[image: Image to illustrate using Automator to perform this answer.]

Then, save the document with a name you'll remember (something like 'Spotify Launcher') in `/Applications`, and replace Spotify in your dock with the Spotify Launcher app that's been created. It will launch both Spotify and the companion app you want to use with Spotify whenever you invoke the application.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this work. Only thing, I was wondering if it could be possible to "observe" an application when it is launched and do an action when this happens. I might apply this behavior to other applications and polluting my application folder with many scripts is not ideal

Comment: In AppleScript, you can use `is_running("Spotify")` to detect whether Spotify is running. You could create a launchd plist that runs the AppleScript every minute to check whether certain apps are running and if they are, to launch other apps. However, that requires running a script every minute to do the check. Alternatively, if you just want to avoid clutter, you could create a folder called `/Applications/Auto Launchers` (or similar) and put all your launchers in there, which would let you avoid it without running a script every minute.