# Is there a way to automate the launch and close of an app based on another app?

Tags: automator, automation

I want app A to launch and close depending on when app B is launched and closed. Is this possible in macOS?

It's sorta mentioned in this questions 
[Can launching an app trigger the launch of another app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153286/can-launching-an-app-trigger-the-launch-of-another-app)

But it's not the same thing. I want to monitor the running of another app. I want it to launch and close without repeated monitoring

Comment: Well, _something_ has to monitor the apps.  You can also set up observers for [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) notifications - are these your applications?

Comment: Have a look at [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) It's [$4.99 at the US App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12), but a free demo is downloadable from the developers website. I use this for many different things, one in particular is it performs some actions when a particular app quits. It uses **AppleScript** to preform what actions you want when an _event_ triggers. If you need help with it, just ask. Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of EventScripts, just a satisfied user of the product.